Proposition 1.17 in Deligne/Milnes "Tannakian Categories".
In Tannakian Categories, prop. 1.17, we are given the following:

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a rigid abelian tensor category. If $U$ is a subojbect of $\mathbf{1}$, then $\mathbf{1} = U \oplus U^{\bot}$. Consequently, $\mathbf{1}$ is a simple object, if $\text{End}(\mathbf{1})$ is a field.

Remark: $U = \text{Ker}(\mathbf{1} \to U^{\vee})$.
The proof proceeds by contemplating an SES $$0 \to U \to \mathbf{1} \to V \to 0$$ where $V = \text{coker}(f:U \to \mathbf{1})$, where $f$ is the monomorphism which identifies $U$ as a subobject of $\mathbf{1}$. We then consider the diagram $\require{AMScd}$
$$\begin{CD} U @>>> \mathbf{1} @>>> V\\ @AAA @AAA @AAA\\
U \otimes U @>>>U @>>> V \otimes U
\end{CD}.$$
Then, they exhibit the natural isomorphisms \begin{align*}\text{Hom}(T \otimes U,T) &\simeq \text{Hom}(T \otimes U \otimes T^{\vee},\mathbf{1})\\ &\underbrace{\simeq}_{(1)} \text{Hom}(T,U^{\vee} \otimes T) \end{align*}
Here, I am not quite sure how we get $(1)$; is it due to rigidity, so that all $[X_1,Y_1] \otimes [X_2,Y_2] \cong [X_1 \otimes X_2,Y_1 \otimes Y_2]$ for all $X_i,Y_i \in \mathcal{C}$, where $[-,-]$ is the internal hom? Furthermore, they claim that, for any object $X$, the largest subobject $T$ of $X$ such that $T \otimes U$ is $0$, is the largest subobject $T$ such that $T \to U^{\vee} \otimes X$ is zero. Why is this?
Do they use the natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}(T \otimes U,T) \simeq \text{Hom}(T,U^{\vee} \otimes T)$ and then post-composed this with the map $\text{id} \otimes \iota$, where $\iota$ is the monomorphism $\iota:T \to X$ which identifies $T$ as a subobject of $X$?
Addendum: I guess a further question I have is the following: How do we even know there exists a largest subobject; what if the $\#$ of isomorphism-classes of subobjects is infinite?
Partial answer:  The first (natural) isomorphism comes from $\text{Hom}(T,X^{\vee}) \simeq \text{Hom}(T \otimes X,\mathbf{1})$, and the second one comes from noting that $U^{\vee} \otimes T \simeq \underline{\text{Hom}}(U,T)$ (due to rigidity), so that $\text{Hom}(T \otimes U,T) \simeq \text{Hom}(T,\underline{\text{Hom}}(U,T))$.

This seems like three separate questions, but the first one is just $- \otimes T^\vee \dashv T \otimes -$ followed by $- \otimes U \dashv U^\vee \otimes -$.

Here's a rewrite of part of the proof.
For any object $T$, the morphism $T\otimes U\rightarrow T$ obtained from
$U\hookrightarrow 1$ by tensoring with $T$, is a monomorphism. This proves the
first equivalence in
$$
T\otimes U=0\iff\text{the map }T\otimes U\rightarrow T\text{ is zero}
\iff\text{the map }T\rightarrow U^{\vee}\otimes T\text{ is zero},
$$
and the second equivalence follows from the canonical isomorphisms
$$
Hom(T\otimes U,T)\overset{1.6.5}{\simeq}Hom(T\otimes U\otimes
T^{\vee},\mathbf{1})\overset{1.6.5}{\simeq}Hom(T,U^{\vee
}\otimes T).
$$
Therefore, for any object $X$,
$$
T:=Ker(X\rightarrow U^{\vee}\otimes X)
$$
is the largest subobject of $X$ such that $T\otimes U=0$. On tensoring the
exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow U^{\perp}\rightarrow 1\rightarrow U^{\vee}\rightarrow0
$$
with $X$, we see that $T\simeq U^{\perp}\otimes X$.
